# How to let a mutex timeout?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I want to let my modem-AT-command-writing-thread only write to the modem's `/dev/ttyUSB3` when the modem-AT-command-reading-thread has seen an "OK" or an "ERROR".

This initially sounds like a job for a `Mutex<()>`, but I have an additional requirement: If the modem-AT-command-reading-thread does not see an "OK" or "ERROR" within three seconds, the writing thread should just get on with sending the next AT command.  i.e. If the reading thread gets nothing, the writing thread should still send one of its AT commands every three seconds.  (Modems' AT command interfaces are often not nicely behaved.)

At the moment, I have a workaround using `mpsc::channel`:

Set-up:

```
let (sender, receiver) = channel::<()>();
```

modem-AT-command-reading-thread:

```
if line.starts_with("OK") || line.contains("ERROR") {
    debug!("Sending go-ahead to writing_thread.");
    sender.send(()).unwrap();
}
```

modem-AT-command-writing-thread:

```
/* This receive is just a way of blocking until the modem is ready. */
match receiver.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(3)) {
    Ok(_) => {
        debug!("Received go-ahead from reading thread.");
        /*
         * Empty the channel, in case the modem was too effusive.  We don't want
         * to "bank" earlier OK/ERRORs to allow multiple AT commands to be sent in
         * quick succession.
         */
        while let Ok(_) = receiver.try_recv() {}
    }
    Err(err) => match err {
        RecvTimeoutError::Timeout => {
            debug!("Timed-out waiting for go-ahead from reading thread.");
        }
        RecvTimeoutError::Disconnected => break 'outer
    },
}
```

I cannot find a `Mutex::lock_with_timeout()`.

How can I implement this properly, using a `Mutex<()>` or similar?

Comment: Please specify what library you are using to actually read the TTY, you can't make claims about APIs without specifying which API you are using.

Comment: I don't think using a channel here is a workaround, I think it's a proper solution. *"This initially sounds like a job for a `Mutex<()>`"* - How so? Mutexes are for exclusive access, not for event waiting. That's what channels are for. I think you have a misunderstanding of what a Mutex is supposed to be. Maybe if you were to talk about an event variable or a semaphore, those are meant for waiting, but mutexes have nothing to do with waiting for something. The only time they wait is if someone else is already accessing the given resource, not if an event didn't happen yet.

Comment: I don't understand you code already do what you want.

Comment: Why two threads? The whole point of using threads is to let different activities happen _concurrently_ with each other. "Concurrently" == "not synchronized." Of course, threads sometimes need to "meet up" and exchange information, but if you have two threads that are _entirely_ synchronous--if they only ever take turns doing things--then you might just as well have only one thread that does all of the things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parking_lot`'s `Mutex`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/type.Mutex.html), it has [`try_lock_for()`](https://docs.rs/lock_api/0.4.7/lock_api/struct.Mutex.html#method.try_lock_for).